# Rewrite Engine with get perameters

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Ok, I have a problem with my RewriteRule. Wenn I use an .htaccess like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteBase /YiiBund/app/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

And try to open `http://127.0.0.1/YiiBund/app/de/site/index?id=5&test=6` the $_GET looks like this:

```
array(1) { 
    ["/de/site/index"]=> string(0) "" 
}
```

But wenn I try with an other RewriteRule:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteBase /YiiBund/app/
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

I'm getting this:

```
array(2) { 
    ["id"]=> string(1) "5" 
    ["test"]=> string(1) "6" 
}
```

Has anyone an idea how to combine those 2 Rules so that i get sommething like this:

```
array(1) { 
    ["/de/site/index"]=> string(0) "" 
    ["id"]=> string(1) "5" 
    ["test"]=> string(1) "6"
}
```

**EDIT:**
I found out, that the problem is the ? by the first parameter. If I would replace the ? with a & would it work, but i can't do this in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `[QSA,L]` instead of just `[L]`

Reference: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html (ctrl+f "qsa")

Answer (score 0):

Example

```
   RewriteRule ^/YiiBund/app/de/site/index/id/(.*)/?$
           /YiiBund/app/de/site/index.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
   RewriteRule ^/YiiBund/app/de/site/index/id/test(.*)/?$ /YiiBund/app/de/site/index/id/test=$1 [L,QSA]
```